# Absolutely positioned header doesn't like being pushed in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Consider the HTML page at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rb8rs70w/2/

It has a "sticky" header via CSS' `position: absolute`.

```
...
<body class="body-menu-push">

    <header role="banner">
        <a href="#" class="menu-toggle" id="show-menu">Menu</a>
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="/">Site Title</a></h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="menu" id="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <!-- menu items here -->
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <article class="content">
        <!-- page content here -->
    </article>
</body>
...
```

Here's the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header[role="banner"] {
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
}
.logo {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.menu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -200px;
    z-index: 1010;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.menu.menu-open {
    left: 0px;
}
.body-menu-push {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
body.body-menu-open {
    left: 200px;
}
.content {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 120px auto;
}
```

Clicking the 'Menu' link opens a push-menu (`#main-menu`) from the left (it is hidden initially), and the rest of the page gets pushed to the right. Clicking the 'Menu' link again will make the push-menu disappear, and the page get back to its original position.

It works fine in Firefox (v31) and IE (v9), but on Chrome (v36.0.1985.143 m) when the push-menu appears, the 'Menu' link disappears (probably because the absolutely positioned header does not get pushed to the right). An interesting thing to note is that if I resize the Chrome window (which repaints the contents, I guess?), the 'Menu' link reappears (that is, the header gets pushed to the right correctly), and while clicking on it again makes the push-menu disappear (and the rest of the page content also gets back to its original position), the sticky header *remains* pushed to the right.

Can somebody point out what can/may be done to fix this in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
body.body-menu-open {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Instead of just left:200px; this should fix in Chrome

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rb8rs70w/3/